# JBehave given composite step is not recognized

Tags: jbehave

I have the following step in JBehave:

```
@When("user enters product $name details page in admin panel")
@Alias("user enters product <name> details page in admin panel")
@Composite(steps = { "Given product <name> exists", "Given page ADMIN_PANEL_PRODUCT_LIST is loaded" })
public void openProductDetailsPage(@Named("name") String name) {
   // ...
}
```

When I try to run a story that uses this step, the exception is being thrown:

```
org.jbehave.core.configuration.Keywords$StartingWordNotFound: 
No starting word found for step 
'Given page ADMIN_PANEL_PRODUCT_LIST is loaded' 
of type 'WHEN' amongst '{AND=And, IGNORABLE=!--, 
GIVEN=Given, THEN=Then, WHEN=When}'
```

What can be wrong? I use a `Given page <name> is loaded` step in other test stories (not composite) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Given page name(as < > ) is loaded` and pass the value `name=ADMIN_PANEL_PRODUCT_LIST`